# Pass date-methods like getTime() as callback

Tags: javascript, function, date, methods, callback

I want to pass Date-object methods such as `getMinutes()`, `getTime()` or `getDay()` as a callback in a function such as:

```
formatDate = (date, callback) => {
    date.callback()
}
```

or more advanced:

```
formatDateArray = (dateArray, callback) => {
        dateArray.map(date => date.callback())
    }
```

What are my alternatives?

Comment: You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to dynamically access the `callback` value: `date[callback]()`. Usage would be like `formatDate(date, "getMinutes")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Fuction.prototype.call` to call the `Date` method by passing the date object as the `this` argument:

```js
const getTime = Date.prototype.getTime;
const getDay = Date.prototype.getDay;
const getMinutes = Date.prototype.getMinutes

formatDateArray = (dateArray, callback) => {
  return dateArray.map(date => callback.call(date))
}

console.log(formatDateArray([new Date(), new Date('August 17, 2020 03:24:00')], getTime));
console.log(formatDateArray([new Date(), new Date('August 17, 2020 03:24:00')], getDay));
console.log(formatDateArray([new Date(), new Date('August 17, 2020 03:24:00')], getMinutes));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
date[callback]()
```

```js
var date=new Date();

var callbacks=["toLocaleString", "getFullYear", "valueOf"];

callbacks.forEach(cb=>console.log(cb+": "+date[cb]()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a curried function for this: the first call takes your callback (and some other optional parameters; more on that later), the second call takes your date:

```js
const formatDate = (fn, ...args) => date => fn.apply(date, args);
```

We can use it with `Date#getDate`:

```js
const getDate = formatDate(Date.prototype.getDate);
```

Because `getDate` is now a function that "waits" for its last parameter (i.e. a date) you can also use it with `Array#map`:

```js
// moon landing dates
const apollo11 = new Date('1969-07-20');
const apollo12 = new Date('1969-11-21');

getDate(apollo11);
//=> 20

[apollo11, apollo12].map(getDate);
//=> [20, 21];
```

Some date methods do take parameters e.g. [`Date#toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString). It would be a shame to not be able to use them. Because they are provided before the actual date we can create specialised functions:

```js
const toUsDate = formatDate(Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString, 'en-US');
const toGbDate = formatDate(Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString, 'en-GB');

toUsDate(apollo11); //=> "7/20/1969"
toGbDate(apollo11); //=> "20/07/1969"
```